# how to sort the list of elements when ascendingorder is selected in the combobox

Tags: java, combobox, swt, listener, e4

I have created a composite which contains the list containg string .I have a combobox in which it has option ascending order and descending order. so now if i select the ascending order in the combobox the list should be sorted in alphabetical order.so how can this be done.

For ex if my composite contains a list  "some","zero","one"
and select ascending order in my combobox it should be sorted and displayed as one,some,zero.

The code to create combobox is as follows

```
String[] ITEMS1 = {"A-Z",  "Z-A"  };
comboSort = new Combo(comboComposite, SWT.NONE);
        comboSort.setBounds(84, 2, 91, 23);
        comboSort.setItems(ITEMS1);


        tabFolder = new TabFolder(topComposite, SWT.NONE);
        GridData tabFolderGD = new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
        tabFolderGD.verticalIndent = 4;
        tabFolderGD.horizontalSpan = 2;
        tabFolder.setLayoutData(tabFolderGD);

        TabItem tabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        tabItem.setText("My created");
        createListViewMycreated(tabFolder,tabItem);
```

the code for tabitem and the listener is as follows

```
private void createListViewMycreated(Composite composite, TabItem ItemMycreated){
        List myCreatedList = new List(composite,SWT.BORDER);
        myCreatedList.setItems(new String[]{"CompSetup_SEMCW8459_TiffanyA005    ","Product_Sirius_Perch_OEM0_AID1_00440245156645    ","SW_SEC Test_DEMO_Sirius   "});
        ItemMycreated.setControl(myCreatedList);
        setDragSource(myCreatedList);

        comboSort.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 System.out.println("hi you selected me in combo box"+comboSort.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("hi you selected me in combo box"+comboSort.getText());
                String ascending =comboSort.getText();
                if (ascending== "A-Z")
                {

                }
            }


            });

    }
```

So now how can we sort the list based on combobox selection

Answer (score 0):

I think your myCreatedList  has list of string.If you want to sort in ascending order do

```
Collections.sort(myCreatedList);
```

And if it is descending then

```
Collections.reverse(myCreatedList);
```

For more informaation on Collections

[check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: @SrikanthBadida ohh okay i thought u need only the sorting stuff.

please check this one this may help u write your code

[Check this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/CreatingaCombowithSortedList.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
      // Re-sort
      String[] items = combo.getItems();
      Arrays.sort(items);
      combo.setItems(items);
```